# Android Espresso server call doesn't persist the token before the next server call

Tags: android, android-espresso

In espresso I call a login method on my app from a login button.

The background asynctask does the login which is successful 200 (it gets a token and should save it). A second server call immediately after is made to get user data - performed from the same asynctask (still on the background thread). Then the response is returned to the app for it to continue.

The second call always comes back:
HTTP code 401
getResponse {"Error":{"Code":401,"Message":"Request requires authorization"}}

Because the token is not seen from the first call when running in espresso but this always runs fine with actual user devices for a few years now.

Any ideas how to make it work with espresso?
I think there should be nothing to do as the 2 calls happen on the background thread away from the UI of the app, and there's only one response callback made at the end of the asynctask...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used the record espresso function in Studio to do the same thing, and it works fine now. 
The code it generates is filled with Thread.sleeps and more excessive code to find a button or edit box, so is a bit ugly but it works correctly and I can do various tests of the app.